# How to Call a function from included library in Android

Tags: android, jar, call

I included a library in my android project, that is now shown under "Android Dependencies".
Its name is MyLibrary, which has Display Function, now I want to call that function of the library, don't know how to call...Any suggestions..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the functions in a library are present in different classes. First access class and make its instance and then call Display function.

Step 1:
First you need to know which class (in library) has this display function. Lets say class ABC has Display function which you want to use in your code.

Step 2:
In your code do this

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
abc.Disaplay();
```

This will give error on class ABC, which means you have to import class first so at the top of your class write:

```
import PackageNnameOfClassInLibrary.ABC;
```

`PackageNnameOfClassInLibrary` is usually like this `com.actionbarsherlock.app`

Comment: @zubair Good to know that. Please mark answer as solved so that it does not appear as unsolved.

Comment: It also requires to add <activity android:name="com.example.libpractice.MyLibrary" /> in the Manifest file...

Comment: Why did you do that ? The library which you added in your project, was it an external library or you copied it in libs folder ?

Comment: @ Syed Zahid Ali I am making an application for that I have to import an external library file in my project, but this library (for which I asked for help) was own creation,But when I will include the other one in the original project am expecting for help too :)

Answer (score 1):

You should now see all classes related to this library. Just import necessary package.

For example in your library you have class

```
package com.example.MyClass;

class MyClass
{
     public void test() {}
}
```

In your main project:

```
import com.example.MyClass;
```

And use this class

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.test();
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit your answer, I can't really understand it...In fact I am new android user.